# What are the steps to transfer a 15 GB file to HDFS cluster

Tags: hdfs

I have a 20 GB file and as per my understanding HDFS cluster is nothing but well coordinated machines and if i want to transfer a 20 GB file how can i transfer it to HDFS and what happens internally when we transfer i to HDFS

Comment: Title says 15. Question says 20. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

File size doesn't matter.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

```
hadoop fs -put /path/to/file hdfs://namenode.address:port/path/in/hdfs
```

> what happens internally when we transfer i to HDFS

It is split into HDFS blocks and distributed onto datanodes

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer so initially name node stores our file and then it would transfer the file to data nodes is it?? But as per my understanding Imagine if 100 customers with 20 GB fie each are trying process their files will name node be in a situation to handle these

Comment: Namenode only stores metadata related to where in all the datanodes that the file is stored